# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'. I am getting this error in this code

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

```
late QuerySnapshot searchSnapshot;`

  initiateSearch() {
    databaseMethods
        .getUserByUsername(searchTextEditingController.text)
        .then((val) {
      print(val.toString());
      setState(() {
        searchSnapshot = val;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget searchList() {
    return searchSnapshot != null ? ListView.builder(
        itemCount: searchSnapshot.docs.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return SearchTile(
            userName: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["name"], //error here 
            userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index].data()["email"] //error here
          );
        }): Container();
  }
```

The code shows a red line at `.data()["name"],` and `.data()["email"]` under [.
The following is the error:

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.
> Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').

Comment: add a ! after the data() call or simple remove the data call completely and only call [index]["name"]

Answer (score 1):

Just use the oparator `?.` like this :

`userName: searchSnapshot.docs[index]?.data()["name"],`

`userEmail: searchSnapshot.docs[index]?.data()["email"]`

And it should be fine.

The `?.` oparator makes the call conditional, so in the case `data()["name"]` or `data()["email"]` is null, it will simply return `null` instead of throwing a NullPointerException.
This [article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/simple-and-bug-free-code-with-dart-operators-2e81211cecfe) might be useful.